# Setting array data in a struct

Tags: c

If when passing to functions we treat parameters `uint32_t data[]` and `uint32_t* data` as both being pointers to an array of data, why is the same not true when setting a member of a struct? Quick example:

```
#include <stdint.h> /* uint32_t */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc */

typedef struct {
    uint32_t data[1024];
} tData;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t *data;
} pData;

int main()
{
    // structs
    pData pdata;
    tData sdata;
    
    // Test 1.
    ///////////////////////////////////
    uint32_t mydata[1024];
    
    // This is OK
    pdata.data = mydata;
    
    // This is not OK
    sdata.data = mydata;
    
    // But this is OK
    memcpy(sdata.data, mydata, 1024);
    
    // Test 2.
    ///////////////////////////////////
    uint32_t *otherdata = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*1024);
    
    // This is OK
    pdata.data = otherdata;
    
    // This is not OK
    sdata.data = otherdata;
    
    // But this is OK
    memcpy(sdata.data, otherdata, 1024);
}
```

In order to satisfy the struct `tData` must I do a `memcpy`? Is this the only way?

Comment: Array declarations are only treated as pointers in function parameters.

Comment: `new` isn't a feature of C

Comment: You can't assign arrays - even if one is in a struct.  A pointer can point somewhere new by assigning it but an array is always a certain place in memory so you can only copy the data - not change where it is stored.

Comment: @h0r53 I have edited the code to be C instead of C++.  I am quite sure the answer to his question is the same in C as it is in C++ so I am not sure if I should have changed the tag to C++ instead?

Comment: I agree that the main confusion was related to types, in particular array initialization versus copying a pointer. I think the edit was reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an attempt to assign an array directly, something like this (without structs)

```
int A[10];
int B[10];
int  *ptr;
ptr = A;    // OK
A = B;      // Not ok
```

assigning array to pointer will make the pointer to point to the first element of the array, while comparing 2 arrays directly is not allowed.

The example with memcpy is equal to copying elements(their memory) one by one. so you can also do something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    sdata.data[i] = mydata[i];
```